# Does this graph property have a name?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

I'm interested in a family of properties of connected simple graphs that comes up in percolation theory.

Let $G$ be a simple connected graph. Now consider the set of subgraphs of $G$ that I will call "cores". A core $C$ of $G$ is a connected subgraph of $G$ with the property that upon "removing" $C$ from $G$ the resulting graph has no edges. I define "removing" as deleting from $G$ all vertices and edges in $C$. Note that a core is not the same as the induced subgraph of a connected dominating set (which makes reference only to the vertices of $C$ and not its edges). For example, the triangle graph has 1 core which is the triangle graph itself, 3 cores that are chains of 3 vertices, and 3 cores that are chains of 2 vertices.

The properties are defined by sums over all the cores:

$f_k(G)=(-1)^{v(G)+1}\sum_{\mathrm{cores}\, C\in G} v(C)^k (-1)^{e(C)}$.

Here $v(C)$ and $e(C)$ are respectively the number of vertices and edges in $C$, and $k$ is a non-negative integer. I've proved that $f_1(G)=0$ for every connected $G$ except for the 1-vertex graph, for which $f_1=1$. I therefore do not need a name for property $f_1$.

What about $f_2$? Here are some special cases. When $G$ is a tree with $n>1$ vertices, then $f_2(G)=0$ unless it is a path; for that case $f_2(G)=2$. Now consider cycles of length $n$. For these the $f_2$ values are $n(n-1)$ . For the complete graphs $f_2(K_n)=n!$ . Perhaps these special cases will help someone make the connection with a known property.

**Addendum:** I welcome suggestions for a better term for what I've called a graph "core". Here is a rewording of the definition, in case there is still confusion. A core $C$ of a connected graph $G$ is a subgraph of $G$ induced by a subset of the *edges* of $G$ and which has the following two properties: (1) $C$ is connected, and (2) every edge of $G$ is incident on a vertex of $C$.

It's not obvious from the definition of $f_k(G)$ that these integers are always nonnegative, but I believe this is true for all positive $k$. Is $f_k(G)$ counting something in $G$? If so, then the definition in terms of cores (and the naming problem) can be avoided.

Comment: When you say "deleting all vertices and edges in C", am I correct that we are deleting all the edges that have at least one endpoint in C?  My point is that some edges which aren't edges in C, also get deleted.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was trying to say.

Comment: so a core $C$ IS an induced (connected) subgraph of $G$ such that $G\setminus C$ is an independent set (or it's trivially empty). Right ? What you mean with > 3 cores that are chains of 3 vertices A "chain" of 3 vertices is the triangle itself. So the complete graph on 3 vertices has 4 cores, not 7

Comment: The cores are not *induced* subgraphs (but they are connected).

Comment: please motivate your comment!! I was trying to give an interpretation of the core definition given in the question, because I understand from the question that what he calls "core" is not the same as core in graph theory. He only names them cores....

Comment: For what it's worth: $f_k\left(G\right) \geq 0$ is now proved in: [Galen Dorpalen-Barry, Cyrus Hettle, David C. Livingston, Jeremy L. Martin, George Nasr, Julianne Vega, Hays Whitlatch, *A positivity phenomenon in Elser's Gaussian-cluster percolation model*, arXiv:1905.11330](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.11330).